# How to auto open a ComboBox when focused?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, dropdown

I have a Form which contains several ComboBoxes.

I want one ComboBox of them to open the elements list when it gets the focus, both from keyboard and mouse.

The `DroppedDown` property of the ComboBox class manages the visibility of the elements list.

The event that most fits my needs is `Enter`, so the code I wrote is:

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

It works, but when directly clicking on the icon located on the right part of the ComboBox which does NOT have the focus, the elements list opens up and the suddenly disappears after its opening.

I've tried many ways to fix this weird behavior, checking the `Focused` property or using other events like `DropDown` or `MouseClick`, without getting any acceptable result.

[image: animation of the problem]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but "the icon on the right of combobox" is an arrow, is it? It's supposed to open if it's closed and to close if it's open?

Comment: Yes, the icon is a triangle/arrow and it lose its original behaviour with this change.

Comment: It is exactly as @MaxB said, when it is dropped down (that the arrow looks pressed) clicking it means you want to close it, otherwise why would you click on it? if you want some functionality other than the usual you must create your own custom control.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I've just edited the question because my explanation was not very precise. Sorry

Comment: @alessaro did my solution work for you?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Unfortunately not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way (which doesn't force you to override a `ComboBox` derived Control's `WndProc`) is to simulate a *HitTest*, testing whether the *MouseDown* occurred on the `ComboBox` button area; then, set `DroppedDown = true;` only if it didn't.

Thus, when the Mouse is clicked on the Button, you won't cause a double effect, moving the Focus in an unexpected way (for the Control).

[GetComboBoxInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) is used to retrieve the correct bounds of the ComboBox Button, whether the current layout is (LTR or RTL).

```
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var combo = sender as ComboBox;
    if (!combo.DroppedDown) {
        var buttonRect = GetComboBoxButtonInternal(combo.Handle);
        if (!buttonRect.Contains(combo.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))) {
            combo.DroppedDown = true;
            Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

Declarations for the `GetComboBoxInfo()` function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct COMBOBOXINFO {
    public int cbSize;
    public Rectangle rcItem;
    public Rectangle rcButton;
    public int buttonState;
    public IntPtr hwndCombo;
    public IntPtr hwndEdit;
    public IntPtr hwndList;
}

internal static Rectangle GetComboBoxButtonInternal(IntPtr cboHandle) {
    var cbInfo = new COMBOBOXINFO();
    cbInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf<COMBOBOXINFO>();
    GetComboBoxInfo(cboHandle, ref cbInfo);
    return cbInfo.rcButton;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class the is inherited from ComboBox:

```
public class Combo : ComboBox
{
     protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!DroppedDown) base.OnClick(e);
     }           
}
```

And in its click call `base.OnClick(e);` if its not dropped down.
use this one instead of combobox. (Basically click event will be ignored if dropped down)

Comment: Even if I assign true to DroppedDown property inside the Click event of the Combo object instance in my form instead of the Enter one, getting focus on the combobox by keyboard (tab press) will not trigger that event.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, all your codes stay, `private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;
}` for instance, just instead of combobox, use combo class

Comment: I've already replaced the ComboBox object instance with your Combo one, but using the Enter event keeps the same beahviour as before.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code on your form constructor:

`this.comboBox1.GotFocus += (sender,args) => comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`

Comment: Probably better change it to: `this.comboBox1.Enter += (snd, evt) => { comboBox1.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow; comboBox1.DroppedDown = true; };`. `sender` could get you in conflict with the current method if it's a event handler (e.g, `Form.Load`). Set the Cursor back to an `Arrow` pointer because in the Enter/GotFocus event it has already been changed to a `Beam` by the Edit control. But, it will not solve the problem reported.

Comment: I've also tried this solution, but it didn't solve my issue.